# Can mobile apps access the phone's settings?

Tags: android, mobile, settings

I had an idea for an android app that would need access to the phone's settings. I am not sure that the app would be able to change any settings (such as screen brightness or turning on wifi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can acces to such things,
change screen brightness:

```
 android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
                android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                value);
```

add this to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

turn on wi-fi

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
manager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

add this to manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the help